# Apply functions to all elements of an array of matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have four 52-by-140 matrices in Matlab. Lets call them `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`:

I want to apply the `eigs` function to a Hessian matrix `[a,b;c,d]` for every point in the original matrix like:

```
for i = 1:52
    for j = 1:140
        eigs([a(i,j),b(i,j);c(i,j),d(i,j)])
    end
end
```

How can I do this in a simpler way, i.e., without `for` loops?

Comment: `for` loops are pretty simple and easy to understand. And in cases like this they may well be faster than other options. Also, why are you using `eigs` instead of `eig` for 2-by-2 matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can probably be done using [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) and defining the action you do in a single iteration using an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) (untested)

```
result = arrayfun(@(a_ij, b_ij, c_ij, d_ij) eigs([a_ij, b_ij; c_ij, d_ij]), ...
    a, b, c, d, 'uniformoutput', false);
```

Note that since `eig` returns a vector, the result can only be stored in a cell array.

You could name the parameters of the anonymous functions `a, b, ...` instead of `a_ij, b_ij, ...`, since they are only used inside the function, but I prefer to it this way to make it clear that inside the function you are using scalars, while the parameters to `arrayfun` are matrices. Personally, I often use upper/lower case to indicate the difference:

```
result = arrayfun(@(a, b, c, d) eigs([a, b; c, d]), A, B, C, D, 'uni', 0);
```

but then you would have to rename your variables.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution to get all of the matrixes teed up:

```
>> abcd = cat(3,a,b,c,d);
>> H = permute(reshape(permute(abcd,[3 1 2]),2,2,[]),[2 1 3]);
>> size(H)
ans =
       2           2        7280
>> i=3;j=2;
>> [a(i,j),b(i,j);c(i,j),d(i,j)]
ans =
    0.4984    0.7935
    0.3524    0.2273
>> H(:,:,i+(j-1)*size(abcd,1))
ans =
    0.4984    0.7935
    0.3524    0.2273
>>
```

Then to run eigs on all 2D matrixes in H:

```
E=arrayfun(@(i)eigs(H(:,:,i)),1:size(H,3),'uni',false);
```